# Create Instance of children using "key"

Tags: c#

I have a base class "Games", and children clases for every game, with its methods making specific action for every game, but some functions are generic. I make the Games class abstract, and every children implements abstract method or using the base clase generic method. Every children have the same functions, but implements diferent in some cases. (i think this is correct way)

```
using System.IO;
using System;

namespace AppGames {

    public abstract class Games 
    { 
        protected string name;

        public Games(string name)  // constructor
        { 
            this.name = name;
        }

        public abstract void Show();  // abstract show method

    }

    public class GameWOW: Games
    { 
        public GameWOW(string name) : base(name) {}  // constructor

        public override void Show()  //override the abstract show method
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Name W : " + name);
        }
    }

    public class GameGW2: Games
    { 
        public GameGW2(string name) : base(name) {}  // constructor

        public override void Show()  //override the abstract show method
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Name G : " + name);
        }
    }

}
```

My problem its to create the instance of every children in the correct case, because i need to call the childrens function when one webservice pass a "key" (not the class name)

Im using a switch, but dont know how to create a "generic" instance of the correct children and call the funcion later.

UPDATE to clarify:

I need to call this some times, but dont duplicate the instances, if i call GameWoW some times, i use only one copy:

```
 switch (game) {

            case "wow":
                className = "GameWoW";
            break;

            case "gw2":
                className = "GameGW2";
            break;

            default:
                className = null;
            break;

        }

        if (className != null) {
          // create instance of the className
          // if exists, use it, if not, create new
        }
```

Thanks.

Comment: How does your `switch` looks like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a nice clean way to do this using `Lazy<Games>`:

```
public class GameCenter
{
    private Dictionary<string, Lazy<Games>> games = new Dictionary<string, Lazy<Games>>()
    {
        { "GameWOW", new Lazy<Games>(() => new GameWOW("wow")) },
        { "GameGW2", new Lazy<Games>(() => new GameGW2("gw2")) },
    };

    public Games GetGameFor(string gameType)
    {
        return games.ContainsKey(gameType) ? games[gameType].Value : null;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Zenth this really is a cleaner way, unless you need side effects upon creating (which may be the case if you're making games). Still a good answer. I'll upvote

Comment: there is a copy paste bug in your code, line 5. `GameWOW` should be `GameGW2`

Comment: One Question: with this system, its possible to pass another dinamic params to "new GameXXX("text")" like "new GameXXX("test", [] params)" ?

Comment: @Zenth - Yes, absolutely. The lambda inside the `Lazy` can contain any code you like.

Comment: @Enigmativity - Sorry for my ignorance (its my first app in C#) how i can pass params to the Dictionary?

Comment: @Zenth - Well, exactly like you said - `new GameXXX("test", param)`. But you're not adding it to the dictionary - it's part of the lambda in the constructor for the `Lazy<Games>` object. It doesn't change the dictionary.

Comment: but, how i can pass the param to the "new GameXX('wow', params)" if in the getGamesFor(gameType) i only specify the "key" of the dictionar? i dont understand how pass the params from GetGameFor

Comment: @Zenth - I think we might be misunderstanding each other a bit. Can you explain what you want to be able to do in more detail?

Comment: when i call the function, using "var game = gc.GetGameFor("GameWOW")", I need to add another param to pass to the class "var game = gc.GetGameFor("GameWOW", someparam)" and the class get it in "new GameWOW("wow", someparam)", the "wow" or "gw2" its static text, i dont know how pass this new param from GetGameFor to the "new GameWOW()" line

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

EDIT: Updated per comments

```
public class GameCenter {
    public Games GetGameFor(string gameType){
        if (!games.ContainsKey(gameType)){
            switch (gameType) {
                case "GameWOW": games.Add("GameWOW", new GameWOW("wow")); break;
                case "GameGW2": games.Add("GameGW2", new GameGW2("gw2")); break;
                default: return null;
            }
        }
        return games[gameType];
    }
    private Dictionary<string, Games> games = new Dictionary<string, Games>();
}
```

Use like this:

```
var gc = new GameCenter();           //create a game center
var game = gc.GetGameFor("GameWOW"); //get a game from the center
game.Show();                         //use the game
//note that you need to keep the gc around, if you make a new GameCenter
//you will get a new game intance when you call GetGameFor
```

Comment: You should rename `Games` to `Game`. `GameWOW` is a `Game`, not a `Games` :)

Comment: Yes, but need to make the instance unique, for dont create new copy every time i call it. (sorry if i not clear with this when i say "generic")
My problem its i need to call the instances some times, this way create some copys, no? (if i call this some times)

Comment: you can replaace the `"GameWOW"` and `"GameGW2"` literals to your keys, then get the games from an instance of the game center class

Comment: How to call? 
GameCenter gc = new GameCenter();
var g = GameCenter.GetGameFor("wow");
g.Show(); ?

Comment: yes, then keep gc around - or you could change `games` and `GetGameFor` to be static (but you should not)

Comment: I get this errors: main.cs(27,39): error CS1501: No overload for method `Add' takes `1' arguments        
/opt/mono/lib/mono/4.5/mscorlib.dll (Location of the symbol related to previous error)
main.cs(28,39): error CS1501: No overload for method `Add' takes `1' arguments        
/opt/mono/lib/mono/4.5/mscorlib.dll (Location of the symbol related to previous error)
Compilation failed: 2 error(s), 0 warnings   

MONO problem?

Comment: sorry, no - it was my bad (I'm coding this in the post not in an IDE so..) should compile now

Comment: Works great! Thanks!
now i change to static and move to my "core" to have the GameCenter global accesible and unique. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67033/discussion-between-zenth-and-alexanderbrevig).